# Unexpected behaviour of degree 2+ polynomials using poly fit

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using poly fit to generate different lines of best fit, The degree 0 and 1 lines are plotted correctly, but for degree 2 and over the polynomials either don't plot or connect all the points. A curve is not plotted.

The code is

```
coef = np.polyfit(x,y,1)

poly1d_fn = np.poly1d(coef)

plt.plot("", "", x, poly1d_fn(x))

print(poly1d_fn)
```

varying the input integer in coef

I have tried removing the empty strings in plt.plot, or replacing them as x, and y, but for degree 2+ the curve is either plotted as lots of lines connecting individual data points or doesn't plot at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937871/how-to-plot-a-polynomial-regression-in-matplotlib https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65055143/matplotlib-polynomial-regression-too-many-lines-showing